# Aggregate Pipeline Atlas Search Stage using C#

Tags: c#, mongodb, asp.net-core, mongodb-atlas-search

I need to make this query using C#:

```
{
$search:{
{
  range:{
    path:"canvasAi.publication_date",
    gte:ISODate("2021-04-01T00:00:00Z"),
    lte:ISODate("2021-10-11T19:11:16.1928297Z")
  }
}
}
}
```

I have this so far:

```
var query = new JObject(
                    new JProperty("$search", new JObject(
                            new JProperty("range", new JObject(
                                    new JProperty("path", "canvasAi.publication_date"),
                                    new JProperty("gte", "ISODate('2021-04-01T00:00:00Z')"),
                                    new JProperty("lte", "ISODate('2021-10-11T19:11:16.1928297Z')")
                                ))
                        ))
                );

            var new_query = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(query);

var pipeline = new BsonDocument[]
            {
                BsonDocument.Parse(new_query)
            };
var result = collection.Aggregate<BsonDocument>(pipeline);
```

I keep getting the error from mongo that **lte** has to be a number, date.

I have the canvasAi.publication_date indexed using Atlas Search and the field is a string in the format give in the string above.

I have been trying for a few hours now and couldnt find a way to make this query.

Comment: looks like, the lte date is not recognized for some reason, try configuring it with BsonDocument directly: `new BsonDocument { { "lte", DateTime.Parse("2021-10-11T19:11:16.1928297Z") } }` and DateTime

Comment: also, does it work without `lte`? I also assume that it's failing only when you call Aggregate (ie it's a server error)

Comment: @dododo if you dont mind, can you give the whole query in the BsonDocument format?

Comment: var query = new BsonDocument
{
 { 
  "$search",
  new BsonDocument
  {
   {
    "range",
    new BsonDocument
    {
     { "path", "canvasAi.publication_date" },
     { "gte", DateTime.Parse("2021-04-01T00:00:00Z") },
     { "lte", DateTime.Parse("2021-10-11T19:11:16.1928297Z") }
    }
   }
  }
 }
};

Comment: That worked. Thank you so much. If you can add this as an answer, i'll accept it.

Comment: I'm not great with C#, but I do know about this repo for C# Atlas Search builders:
https://github.com/mongodb-labs/mongo-csharp-search

Comment: It doesn't support range easily

Comment: @dododo Is there any clear documentation for how to construct complex queries for the aggregation pipeline for atlas search? i basically have to construct a query with like 10 different criteria including filters, should, must, must not, etc and i am not able to find any decent documentation for atlas search with c#. Much appreciated for any help that you can provide.

Comment: I know this: https://docs.atlas.mongodb.com/reference/atlas-search/query-syntax/#std-label-query-syntax-ref, https://docs.atlas.mongodb.com/reference/atlas-search/tutorial/

Comment: mongo c# driver doesn't support atlas search via any builders, so you should construct raw MQL requests for it

Comment: AFAIK, this one github.com/mongodb-labs/mongo-csharp-search is more POC and not officially released/supported yet

Comment: @dododo  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69543017/use-compound-and-range-operator-together-in-atlas-search

Can you attempt this when you have time? Thanks.

Comment: I don't use atlas search now and don't have way to check it, try asking here https://www.mongodb.com/community/forums/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

looks like, the lte date is not recognized for some reason. Try using the BsonDocument form:

```
    var query = new BsonDocument
    {
        { 
            "$search",
            new BsonDocument
            {
                {
                    "range",
                    new BsonDocument
                    {
                        { "path", "canvasAi.publication_date" },
                        { "gte", DateTime.Parse("2021-04-01T00:00:00Z") },
                        { "lte", DateTime.Parse("2021-10-11T19:11:16.1928297Z") }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

You can refer the blog https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/mongodb-atlas-search-index-in-c-sharp-build-aggregation-pipeline-with-con

```
var searchStage = @ "{$search: {index:'" + Constant.SEARCH_INDEX + "'," + searchBy + ": {query:'" + SearchKeyword + "', path:" + Constant.SEARCH_PATH + "}}}";
          var pipeline = new EmptyPipelineDefinition < CollectionRecord > ()
            .AppendStage < CollectionRecord, CollectionRecord, CollectionRecord > (searchStage)
            .Match(PanelFilter);
```

After defining the stages in a string format, we can have a pipeline definition and execute by calling aggregate method.

```
entities = await _collectionRepository.AggregateAsync(search.Pipline, search.Sort, search.Projection);
//Some code

public Task<List<CollectionRecord>> AggregateAsync(PipelineDefinition<CollectionRecord, CollectionRecord> pipeline,
  SortDefinition<CollectionRecord> sortDefinition = null, ProjectionDefinition<CollectionRecord, CollectionRecord> projection = null)
{
  if (projection != null && sortDefinition != null)
      pipeline = pipeline.Sort(sortDefinition).Project(projection);
  else if (projection != null)
      pipeline = pipeline.Project(projection);

  return Collection.Aggregate(pipeline).ToListAsync();
}
```

Comment: Your answer only contains code. I recommend that you don't only post code as an answer, but _also_ provide an explanation about what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes. Can you [edit] your answer to include this?